# Change BLE scanning frequency on iOS

Tags: ios, bluetooth-lowenergy, intervals, frequency, scanning

I am developing mobile apps for iOS using the BLE capabilities of an iPhone. I did not find a way to change BLE scanning frequency/interval.
I am using a react native lib called: "react-native-ibeacon" which does not seem to offer a specific method to change the scanning frequency.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You cannot control the scanning interval for BLE on iOS.

Comment: Thank you for the response @Paulw11.